# Change cell color based on MYSQL value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to change td color using if statement but somehow my code is not affecting all rows

1. this is my code :

   ```
   require_once("../model/materiel.class.php" . "");
   $mt=new materiel();
   $data=$mt->afficher_tous1();

   echo '<table id="customers2" class="table datatable table-striped">';
   echo "<thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Qte disponible</th>
       <th>Alert</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>";

   echo "<tbody>";
     foreach($data as $t){

      echo "<tr>";
        if ($t['qte_disponible_m'] == 0){
        echo "<td bgcolor='red'>".$t['qte_disponible_m']."</td>";
        }else if ($t['qte_disponible_m'] > $t['alert_m']){
         echo "<td bgcolor='green'>".$t['qte_disponible_m']."</td>";
          }else if ($t['qte_disponible_m'] == $t['alert_m']){
         echo "<td bgcolor='yellow'>".$t['qte_disponible_m']."</td>";
        }

       echo "<td>".$t['alert_m']."</td>";

   echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</tbody>";
   echo"</table>";
   ```

   2. the problem i have see the screenshot below :

   If statement is like jumping next row

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It would be useful to know what `$t['alert_m']` was as its used in your if testing! And it is not shown in your picture. But that is where you need to look to solve this issue. It is probably `< $t['qte_disponible_m']` in every other iteration of your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class with the CSS `background-color` property (with `!important` if needed) to the TD instead of bgcolor. The bgcolor gets overwritten by the `table-striped` class.